# How to call a method of component in plugin

Tags: vue.js, plugins, components, nuxt.js

I made a component called dialog, and I want to make it plugin and register it as a global function.

However, I don't know how to access the component from plugin and call the component's method.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import AlertDialog from '@/components/AlertDialog'

const methods = {
  openDialog: (
    maxWidth,
    title,
    message
  ) =>
    AlertDialog.openDialog(
      maxWidth,
      title,
      message
    ),
  closeDialog: () => AlertDialog.closeDialog()
}

Vue.prototype.openDialog = methods.openDialog
Vue.prototype.closeDialog = methods.closeDialog
```

This is a dialog_plugin.js.

But it doesn't work.

edit
 ::

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-if="isShow"
    v-model="isShow"
    :max-width="maxWidth ? maxWidth : 290"
  >
    <v-card>
      ...
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isShow: false,
      maxWidth: null,
      title: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openDialog(
      maxWidth,
      title
    ) {
      this.isShow = true
      ...
    },
    closeDialog() {
      this.isShow = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is AlertDialog.vue

Comment: I suspect `AlertDialog` is not a component *instance*, rather the component definition object, right?

Comment: This is the import of the AlertDialog.vue file. Added content for the file. Please check.

Comment: You can't call `AlertDialog.openDialog` because `AlertDialog` is not an instance of that component. You need to have an `AlertDialog` somewhere in the template with a `ref` to it so that you can call methods on it. Perhaps put in the root component template, and then you can call `this.$root.$refs.dialog.openDialog`.

Comment: I added a ref to the template of the AlertDialog component, but I can't see 'dialog' in $refs. Do I need to add this component to layout? If so, please let me know if you have a good way to make the dialog a global function, as there are limits to changing the layout structure.

Comment: The ref shouldn't be in the AlertDialog template, you need to actually have `<AlertDialog ref="dialog">` elsewhere. You must have `<AlertDialog>` somewhere for an instance of it to be created; just importing AlertDialog isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

A component's methods are only intended to be called from within the component itself. Trying to expose them to be called by outside code is really going against the way Vue is designed to work.

If you want to affect the state of a component from outside of itself, there are a couple of ways:

1. **Props** - Rather than `isShow` being a piece of the AlertDialog's state, you would pass this value in as a prop. That way the parent component can change the value to show/hide the alert as needed.
2. **Vuex** - If you needed to have a single instance of a component in your app (e.g. for a toast display), having it receive its state from a [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) store would make it easy to display messages from any part of your app.
3. **An Event Bus** - For a simpler app where you don't want to bring in Vuex, you can always [use an instance of Vue as an event bus](https://css-tricks.com/using-event-bus-to-share-props-between-vue-components/), to control your component by emitting events from anywhere else in your app. Your component can then listen for these events and show/hide as needed.